# Dynamically color or highlight current sculpt stroke

Tags: sculpting

When I sculpt, if the current stroke I was making was a different color or highlighted, I then could see how I was effecting the vertices better. After the stroke, I could change angles and take an even better look. When I start another stroke, the last stroke would become the same color as the rest of the mesh and the new stroke would become highlighted. Even better, have the option of a number of strokes that would be highlighted, but just one would be nice.

Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: This looks more like a feature request and I don't think this is possible (yet). To preview model better while sculpting, use Matcaps, set up windows to have several views of the model, rotate the view frequently and so on.

Comment: I was afraid it would sound that way, but I had to ask, because I didn't see anything when I searched, yet I've found Blender so far to have features that required the integration of a few basic tools. I was hoping at least for that.